# How to provide horizontal scroll bar for form.io data-grid component?

Tags: datagrid, horizontal-scrolling, formio, form.io, angular-formio

Using the form.io data-grid component , We can drag and drop our columns to that data-grid component.

For Example a simple data-grid component with two or three columns may look like below :

[image]

It is okay for less number of columns. If number of columns increases upto 6 or 7 , the data-grid view in not okay. **The columns gets shrink in size and data goes unreadable** as below :

[image]

So , someone please help me on this. Is there any way to give horizontal scroll bar or customize the each column width using form.io ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add absolute width for each component inside data grid in layout tab.
[image]

This will allow the data grid to have a horizontal scroll.

[image]